# Error occuring resgiter the Redhat 6.4?

Tags: linux, rhel

I'm trying to register the Redhat from RHN Registration. This report the bug `There was an error while populating the profile  This error shouldn't have happened. If you'd like to help us improve this program, please file a bug at
bugzilla.redhat.com. Including the relevant parts of '/var/log/up2date'` I'm report the Bug in the Red Hat Bugzilla? How can i register the Redhat?

Comment: Either report the bug as indicated, or post the relevant parts of that log file here. There's absolutely no info in what you posted that could enable anyone to help you aside from wild guesses.